# Generating a random number one time, but generates thousands of times

Tags: random

I'm trying to generate ONE number, but every time I do this it prints out thousands of numbers.

Here is my code:

```
Random r = new Random();
int number;
int number2;

for(int i = 0; i != 1; i++) {
    number = r.nextInt(6);
    number2 = r.nextInt(6);
    Font fnt = new Font("arial", 1, 200);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.setFont(fnt);
    g.drawString(number + number2 + "", Program.WIDTH/2-100, 300);
}
```

Comment: try this `for(int i = 0; i == 1; i++) { }`

Comment: You should add a tag to indicate what programming language

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Random r = new Random();

    int number;
    int number2;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

        number = r.nextInt(6);
        number2 = r.nextInt(6);

        Font fnt = new Font("arial", 1, 200);

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(fnt);
        g.drawString(number + number2 + "", Program.WIDTH/2-100, 300);

    }
```

Comment: You should explain exactly what you changed and what problem it solves.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code it looks like your are trying to run the loop once.  If this is the case, remove the FOR loop. If this code is in a function that runs on a screen refresh, it will generate thousands of random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that making functions give you more flexibility later :)

For example :

```
public static int myRandom(int min, int max) {
    if(max >= min)    {
        Random r = new Random();
        return r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }
}
```

Comment: Number of a given range

Comment: Please format your answer correctly before posting next time.

Comment: Thanks for your attention